# Setting up a JAR to be used automatically when compiling and running Java programs

Tags: java, selenium

I am using the following command to compile and run Selenium programs.

```
javac -classpath .:"/Users/ravigupta/Downloads/WebDriverZen/SelSerStdAln2400.jar" WebDriverTest.java

java -classpath .:"/Users/ravigupta/Downloads/WebDriverZen/SelSerStdAln2400.jar" WebDriverTest
```

What can I do to avoid specifying the location of Selenium JAR everytime I compile and run code?

Answer (score 0):

What your doing is good practice, but if you really want to avoid it then add it to jre/lib/ext

Comment: Thanks, where do I find that on OS X Mavericks?

Comment: I use windows - but its probably echo $JAVA_HOME from the command prompt, then look under that directory

Comment: If this is a school project I'd just make it into a script file. If this is for a real project I'd probably use eclipse or something similar and add the libraries.